# A complemented lattice satisfying de Morgan's laws is an ortholattice?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, lattice-orders

Suppose you have a bounded, complemented lattice $\mathfrak{L} = \left<L, \vee, \wedge, \neg, 1, 0\right>$ that satisfies De Morgan's laws. I want to prove that this is an ortholattice. The first condition $a \leq b \implies \neg b \leq \neg a$ was straightforward, but I am struggling a lot with the second condition.

That is, given $\neg (a \vee b) = \neg a \wedge \neg b$ and $\neg (a \wedge b) = \neg a \vee \neg b$ for all $a, b \in L$, I'd like to show that

$$\neg\neg a = a$$ for all $a, b, \in L$.

When I looked this up in a textbook, what I saw was:
$\neg \neg a = \neg (\neg a \vee \neg a) = \neg \neg a \wedge \neg \neg a = a \wedge a = a $

I can't, however, understand how one gets $\neg \neg a \wedge \neg \neg a = a \wedge a$ without assuming $\neg\neg a = a$.

I also tried proving this in some other way but failed.

I need one of two things:

1. An alternative proof, or
2. An explanation why $\neg \neg a \wedge \neg \neg a = a \wedge a$ doesn't assume $\neg\neg a = a$

Comment: How exactly are you defining $\neg$ here?

Comment: @GitGud It looks like he's defining it as the NOT operator

Comment: If $a \sqcap \neg a = 0$ and $a \sqcup \neg a = 1$.

Comment: Do you know that the lattice is UC (uniquely complemented)? So $\lnot a$ is the *unique* complement?

Comment: Unfortunately, the statement just says "complemented," not uniquely complemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't true in general unless the lattice is uniquely complemented.  For instance, consider the diamond lattice $M_3$, with elements $\{0,a,b,c,1\}$ such that $0 < a,b,c < 1$ and none of $a,b,c$ are comparable to each other.  We can assign complements $\neg a = b$ and $\neg b = c$ and $\neg c = a$.  You can check that de Morgan's laws hold, as does the order-reversing condition, but $\neg \neg a  \neq a$.